# ant rebuilddb command fails - exec returned: 127

Tags: php, symfony, ant, debian

When I'm executing the `ant rebuilddb` command on a project it seems that ant can't find the php executable.

I get the following error:

```
Buildfile: /var/www/html/aac_test/build.xml

rebuilddb:
 [exec] /usr/bin/env: php
 [exec] : File or Directory not found (translation by me from German to English)

BUILD FAILED
/var/www/html/aac_test/build.xml:83: exec returned: 127
```

In my build.xml there is the following in line 83

```
<target name="rebuilddb" description="removes and recreates the database with default development data">
    <exec dir="${server}" executable="bin/console" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="cache:clear" />
    </exec>
...
```

It should execute some symfony console commands.

Where `which php` gives me `/usr/bin/php`

So my question is - Why ant can't find the php executable?

**Notes:**

My Dev OS in Vbox is Debian Jessi, php5-cli is installed and I need to type `php app/console somecommand` to run symfony console commands. It seems there is something broken with cli. All php5 components where removed, purged and reinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution by myself. It was a problem with Virtualbox. The project directory of the dev vm is a symlink from a shared folder with a Windows 7 as Host.

The problem was, that the format of the app/console file was manipulated by Windows, so Debian could not read it in an ordinary way.

I solved this by reformating the console script with `dos2unix console`.
Hope it helps someboy with a similar problem.